# QTreeView Cannot use single click selection after slide multi selection

Tags: c++, qtreeview

I'm writing a GUI that will run on a touchscreen device in c++ using Qt; I have a **QTreeView** which display some images using **QFileSystemModel**; I have a **FileFrame** class and **MyTreeView** class (that inherit **QTreeView**) which handle mouse release event; I intercept mouse release event to show information about selected file (you can select whatever you want, but when you release the mouse i want to get information about all the selected file in that moment).

When i start the application i can select and deselect multiple files with single click and it works great, every time mouse (finger) is released the program print file information! but if i try to select files sliding the finger on them it works for the first time and then is impossible to completely deselect the start file, or select/deselect with single click every other file.

I don't understand why using the gesture override the single click selection feature.
I have enabled "multiple Selection" in MyTreeView ui designer properties.

EDIT: I found a workaround simply disabling multiple selection with a slide:

-capture in MyTreeView the mouse move event

-accept it and do nothing

For my app is enough but i would like to know what was the problem!

FileFrame.h

```
class CFileFrame : public QWidget, public CPageBase
{
 Q_OBJECT
public:
explicit CFileFrame(QWidget *parent = 0, CImagePreview *preview = 
nullptr);
~CFileFrame();

void ApplyLanguage(type_enmLanguage lang);
void updateSelectedFileInfo(QModelIndexList selectedFile);

private slots:
void on_btn_Preview_clicked();
void on_btn_Back_clicked();

void on_treeView_doubleClicked(const QModelIndex &index);


private:
Ui::CFileFrame              *ui;
QFileSystemModel            *m_pFileSystemModel;
CImagePreview               *m_pImagePreviewFrame;
CItemDelegateTreeViewZoom   *m_pmyItemDelegate;
};
```

FileFrame constructor:

```
CFileFrame::CFileFrame(QWidget *parent, CImagePreview *imagePreview) 
:
QWidget(parent),
ui(new Ui::CFileFrame)
{
ui->setupUi(this);

m_pImagePreviewFrame = imagePreview;
//Start from image directory in executable path
QString path = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath();
path += "/";
path += "images/";

m_pFileSystemModel = new QFileSystemModel();

m_pFileSystemModel->setFilter(QDir::AllDirs | QDir::Files 
|QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
m_pFileSystemModel->setRootPath(path);
m_pFileSystemModel->rootDirectory();

QStringList filter;
filter << "*.png";
filter << "*.jpg";
filter << "*.jpeg";

m_pFileSystemModel->setNameFilters(filter);

//Don't show filtered files
m_pFileSystemModel->setNameFilterDisables(false);

ui->treeView->setModel(m_pFileSystemModel);
ui->treeView->setRootIndex(m_pFileSystemModel->index(path));

//Item delegate for increase tree view icon
m_pmyItemDelegate = new CItemDelegateTreeViewZoom(this);
ui->treeView->setItemDelegate(m_pmyItemDelegate);

//    ui->treeView->setUniformRowHeights(true);
//Hide unnecessary columns
ui->treeView->hideColumn(1);
ui->treeView->hideColumn(2);
ui->treeView->hideColumn(3);
ui->treeView->hideColumn(4);
}
```

FileFrame method to call after selection is finished:

```
void CFileFrame::updateSelectedFileInfo(QModelIndexList 
selectedFile)
{
if(selectedFile.length() == 1)
{
    //Get selected file's information
    QFileInfo selectedFileInfo = m_pFileSystemModel- 
  >fileInfo(selectedFile.at(0));
    //If selected file is a directory display it's path
    if(selectedFileInfo.isDir())
    {
        ui->lineEdit->setText(selectedFileInfo.absoluteFilePath());
    }
    //If is a file display is information
    else
    {
        QString tmp = "Size: ";
        float number = 0.0;
        float size = (float) selectedFileInfo.size();
        if( size < 1024*1024) //In KiloBytes
        {
            number = size / 1024;
            tmp += QString::number((double) number, 'f', 2);
            tmp += " Kb - Created: ";
        }
        else if(size < 1024*1024*1024) //MegaBytes
        {
            number = size / (1024*1024);
            tmp += QString::number((double) number, 'f', 2);
            tmp += " Mb - Created: ";
        }
        else //Gigabytes
        {
            number = size / (1024*1024*1024);
            tmp += QString::number((double) number, 'f', 2);
            tmp += " Gb - Created: ";

        }
        //Get time and date of creation
        tmp += selectedFileInfo.created().toString("d/m/yy hh:mm");
        tmp += " - Photo(yes)";
        ui->lineEdit->setText(tmp);
    }
}
//If is selected more than one
else if(selectedFile.length() >= 2)
{
    ui->lineEdit->setText("Multiple Selection");
}
else
{
    ui->lineEdit->setText("No File Selected");
}
```

}

MyTreeView.h:

```
class CMyTreeView : public QTreeView
{
public:
CMyTreeView(QWidget *parent);


private:
int     m_nStart;
int     m_nEnd;
CFileFrame      *m_pParent;




private slots:
//        void selectionChanged(const QItemSelection & selected, const 
QItemSelection & deselected);
    virtual void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent * event);
//          bool viewportEvent(QEvent *event);
};
```

MyTreeView Constructor:

```
CMyTreeView::CMyTreeView(QWidget *parent):
QTreeView(parent)
{

m_pParent = (CFileFrame*) parent;

}
```

MyTreeView method:

```
void CMyTreeView::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{

//DEBUG
qDebug("MOuse released");
////////////////////
event->accept();
QModelIndexList selectedFiles = this->selectionModel()- 
>selectedIndexes();
m_pParent->updateSelectedFileInfo(selectedFiles);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution! I've read better the documentation [Here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#event) and found that you have to call the parent method for complement handling (i wanted to do an additional task on mouse release, not completely override it);

So i just added a line at the end of the method and everything works fine!

```
void CMyTreeView::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{
event->accept();
QModelIndexList selectedFiles = this->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
m_pParent->updateSelectedFileInfo(selectedFiles);
QTreeView::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
}
```

Shame on me!